# Interfaz de typescript

Tags: nodejs, typescript

Tengo el siguiente código después de hacer una actualización, datos que me devuelve la actualización asignarla a una constante con una interfaces pero me sale que no se puede asignar o que bien debería asignarla con `null` adjunto una pequeña imagen:

```
const saveUser: usuarioInterface = await Usuario.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, actualizarUsuarioId, { new: true });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Es posible que tengas una configuración de typescript más estricta de lo habitual. Comprueba si en el fichero `tsconfig.json` tienes la siguiente entrada:

```
"strictNullChecks": true
```

Esta entrada hace que `null` o `undefined` no se consideren valores válidos de ningún tipo, con lo que tienes que añadirlos explícitamente. Por lo que se ve de tu captura, el problema es que la llamada a `Usuario.findOneAndUpdate` puede devolver un null, lo que no es un valor del tipo `usuarioInterface` válido.

Por tanto, tienes dos soluciones: asegurarte de poner esa opción a `false` (también puede ser la opción `"strict"`, que incluye los *null checks* entre otras comprobaciones) o añadir null como posible valor de saveUser:

```
const saveUser: (usuarioInterface | null) = await ...
```

Comment: Gracias amigo me servio de mucho @pablo Lozada