# tengo este error ts2322 para angular

Tags: angular, typescript

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { Libro } from '../libro.modelo';
import { LIBROS } from '../mocks';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-libro-detalle',
  templateUrl: './libro-detalle.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./libro-detalle.component.css'],
})
export class LibroDetalleComponent implements OnInit {
  libro: Libro = new Libro();

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
      let id = +!params.get('id');
      this.libro = LIBROS.find((item) => item.id === id);
    });
  }
}
```

Basicamente en `this.libro` me salta este mensaje-> El tipo 'Libro | undefined' no se puede asignar al tipo 'Libro'.
El tipo 'undefined' no se puede asignar al tipo 'Libro'.ts(2322)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Interfaz de typescript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/411295/interfaz-de-typescript)

Answer (score 1):

es una de dos, o el servicio Mock que tienes de libros retorna los libros sin el tipado correcto o ese LIBROS.find no esta retornando nada.

si haces esto y arroja un error de tipo sobre item el error es que el Array/Servicio LIBROS no esta correctamente tipado.

```
this.libro = LIBROS.find((item: Libro) => item.id === id);
```

si es un array deberia ser:

```
const LIBROS: Libro[] = [{ libro1 }, { libro2 }..etc]
```

tambien considera usar una Interface en lugar de una Clase:

```
export interface Libro {
   titulo: string
   autor: string
   anio: number
   precio: number
   existencias: boolean
}
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda todo esto.

Comment: No consigo sacarlo de las formas que me dices, pero no es culpa tuya, es que estoy aprendiendo angular y se me escapan muchas cosas. Muchas gracias igualmente, lo intentare sacar de alguna forma.